# Strange Fold Info Showing in Gutter

Tags: folding, filetype-python

It's only happening in one of my `.py` files when opened with vim, I am getting some kind of fold info in the gutter that shouldn't be there - made up of the characters '2', '-' and '|'.

[image]

I disabled all my plugins to test if there is some plugin issue, but the problem remains. I deleted the files pertaining to this .py in the `views` folder in case that may be the issue, but to no avail.

The foldmethod is set to indent. If I change the foldmethod to marker then that annoying info in the gutter goes away, but comes back once I reselect indent method.

The folds look normal when folded however:

[image]

Anyone know what is happening, or how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you see is the ['foldcolumn'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27foldcolumn%27) setting for opened folds. If you don't want it, simply disable it: `:set foldcolumn=0` To find out where it was set, enter `:verbose set foldcolumn?` You might also play with increasing the foldcolumn value, so that the display looks a little bit better.